# ReactJS client and ExpressJS backend application production problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am new in reactjs and nodejs.I made an application with react frontend and express backend. There are axios post and get requests for get data from mssql database via express.

When the project in production level, I write the IPv4 address and port for access dashboard from another device in local network. After build,when I use for example localhost:5000 for requests, I can see all datas which are come from database in the device which react project running but with this I cant see datas from android phone in local network.

What should I do? Isn't there any other way than writing a static IP address? This project can be run different machines.

I am sorry for my spelling mistakes.

Comment: You can save server endpoint in environment variable and use it in client application. That way only env variable will change when application is deployed on different servers and application code is not impacted.

Comment: Actually, I don't know how can I  do that. Can you explain more ? In client side how should I save endpoint ? should I make it in .env  ?

Comment: Maybe this link will help - https://trekinbami.medium.com/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5